# Python Thread/Queue fast data I/O missing or duplicated Get() Packets

Tags: multithreading, sockets, python-3.x, arduino, queue

Have written a simple program which logs data from an Arduino Mega with an Ethernet shield, transfer rate is typically 0.0008-0.001 seconds for each 48byte packet.  I have created one thread which opens a socket and gets a packet from the arduino and puts it in the queue in a continuous loop, also prints a debug message in the console, according to the console I have not seen it skip a beat yet when receiving packets from the socket.  There is another thread which gets a waiting packet from the queue and prints it to the console.  The second thread however sometimes skips or duplicates packets as it pulls them off the queue and I therefore loose valuable data.  Im not sure what I am doing wrong here as I have tried several different iterations of calling put and get.  Before I rewrite it for multiprocess perhaps someone can shed light on the issue?

```
import sys, os, time, datetime  
import socket from threading 
import Thread from PyQt4 
import QtCore, QtGui 
import queue  
import binascii

q = queue.Queue(maxsize=0) 
Running = False

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        global Running, thread, thread2, thrAdruino, thrPackets
        if Running == True:
            Running = False
            self.button.setText('Start')
            thrAdruino.isRunning = False
            thrPackets.isRunning = False
            print ('stop')
        else:
            Running = True
            self.button.setText('Stop')

            thrAdruino = talkArduino()
            thread = Thread(target=thrAdruino.run, daemon=True )
            thread.start()

            thrPackets = parsePackets()
            thread2 = Thread(target=thrPackets.run, daemon=True )
            thread2.start()

            print ("Start")   



class talkArduino(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.isRunning = True
    def run(self):
        print('Arduino: Thread Started')
        TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER = bytearray(48)
        TCP_IP, TCP_PORT, BUFFER_SIZE = '192.168.1.177', 502, 48
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print('Arduino: Socket Opening')
        s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
        print('Arduino: Socket Opened, sending start command')
        s.send(bytes(1))
        while self.isRunning == True:
            s.recv_into(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER)
            if TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER[0] == 48:
                q.put(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER, block=True, timeout=1)
                print ('Arduino: ',  binascii.hexlify(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER) )
        s.close()
        print('Arduino: Closed Socket')



class parsePackets(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.isRunning = True
    def run(self):
        print ('packet parser thread started')
        print (q.qsize())
        buffer1 = bytearray()
        while self.isRunning == True:
            try:
                print (q.qsize())
                buffer1 = q.get(block=True, timeout=1)
                print ("Packets: ", binascii.hexlify(buffer1) )
            except q.Empty:
                pass



if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have also included the Arduino Mega Sketch for completeness.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,177);
byte Buffer[] = { 0x30, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
                  0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f,
                  0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x1b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f};
// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use 
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(502);

// Define various ADC prescaler
const unsigned char PS_16 = (1 << ADPS2);
const unsigned char PS_32 = (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS0);
const unsigned char PS_64 = (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS1);
const unsigned char PS_128 = (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS0);


void setup() {
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // set up the ADC
  ADCSRA &= ~PS_128;  // remove bits set by Arduino library
  // you can choose a prescaler from above.
  // PS_16, PS_32, PS_64 or PS_128
  ADCSRA |= PS_32;    // set our own prescaler to 64 

  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV2);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  unsigned int i;
  unsigned int AI;
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");

    // an http request ends with a blank line
    while (client.connected()) {
          for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
            AI =analogRead(i);
            Buffer[i*2+4] = highByte(AI);
            Buffer[i*2+5] = lowByte(AI);
          }
          Buffer[1] +=1;
          client.write(Buffer, 48);
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disonnected");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you **put()** and **get()**, you are putting and getting a reference to the object -- not a copy of the object.  This line puts a reference to the original bytearray()

```
q.put(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER, block=True, timeout=1)
```

When you get:

```
buffer1 = q.get(block=True, timeout=1)
```

the buffer1 is now a reference to the same bytearray as TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER.  If the first thread changes the contents of the buffer, the second thread sees the same data.

What happens depends on exactly how the two threads interleave.  The symptoms you describe can be seen by writing possible ordering of the two threads.

The normal case, the get() prints correctly:

```
# case 1 - what you want to happen
s.recv_into(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER)  # receive = "packet1"
q.put(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER, block=True, timeout=1) # push reference to buffer - 1 item on Q
buffer1 = q.get(block=True, timeout=1) # pop reference to buffer - 0 item on Q
# buffer1 is correct at this point = "packet1"
```

How the get() drops a packet:

```
# case 2 - get is delayed a bit - 2 recv's before first get()
s.recv_into(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER) # write into buffer "packet1"
q.put(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER, block=True, timeout=1) # push reference to buffer - 1 item on Q
s.recv_into(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER) # write into buffer "packet2" - overwrites buffer
buffer1 = q.get(block=True, timeout=1) # pop reference to buffer - 0 item onQ   
# buffer1 has missed one - the buffer now contains "packet2" - never will see "packet1"
```

How the get() sees the same packet twice:

```
# case 3 - get is delayed a bit longer - 2 puts() before first get()
s.recv_into(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER) # write into buffer "packet1"
q.put(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER, block=True, timeout=1) # push reference to buffer - 1 item on Q
s.recv_into(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER) # write into buffer "packet2" - overwrites buffer
q.put(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER, block=True, timeout=1) # push reference to buffer - 2 item on Q
buffer1 = q.get(block=True, timeout=1) # pop reference to buffer - 1 item on Q    
# buffer1 has missed one - the buffer now contains "packet2"
buffer1 = q.get(block=True, timeout=1) # pop reference to buffer - 0 item on Q    
# buffer1 has missed one - the buffer still contains "packet2"
```

To fix this, the first thread must push a unique **copy** of the data onto the Q and destroy its reference.  You are giving the data to the Q which then owns it until the receiver takes it.  Simply creating a new buffer every time should fix:

```
    while self.isRunning == True:
        s.recv_into(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER)
        if TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER[0] == 48:
            print ('Arduino: ',  binascii.hexlify(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER) )
            # you have to print before pushing onto Q
            # once it is on the Q, it is no longer safe for this thread to use
            q.put(TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER, block=True, timeout=1)
            # do not use the object any more - you have given it away
            # create a new object for the next receive
            TCP_RECEIVE_BUFFER = bytearray(48)
```